# Create two log files from shared log4net.config file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, log4net

I have two console applications that share common app.config and log4.net files in the same solution.  The first console app calls the second console app, but needs to write to a different log file for each application.  Both apps share the same binary folder.

My log4.net file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>

  <appender name="SchedulerService" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="c:\\logs\\MailChimp\\Scheduler.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <header value="[--------------------------------------------------]&#13;&#10;" />
      <footer value="&#13;&#10;" />
      <conversionPattern value="%-5level %date [%thread] %logger  
                  %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      <!-- set your class name here -->
      <LoggerToMatch value="MailChimp.MailingPlan" />
    </filter>
    <!--  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" /> -->
  </appender>

  <appender name="MailChimp" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="c:\\logs\\MailChimp\\MailChimpUploader.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <header value="[--------------------------------------------------]&#13;&#10;" />
      <footer value="&#13;&#10;" />
      <conversionPattern value="%-5level %date [%thread] %logger  
                  %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      <!-- set your class name here -->
      <LoggerToMatch value="MailChimp.MailChimpUploader" />
    </filter>
    <!--<filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" /> -->
  </appender>


  <!-- Set the default logging level and add the active appenders -->
   <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="SchedulerService" />
    <appender-ref ref="MailChimp" /> 
  </root>   

</log4net>
```

Only one of the log files gets written to and apparently one logging process is locking the file on the other because Log4Net is generating the following error:

```
log4net:ERROR [RollingFileAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. 
      Unable to acquire lock on file 
      c:\logs\MailChimp\MailChimpUploader.txt. 
      The process cannot access the file 
      'c:\logs\MailChimp\MailChimpUploader.txt' 
      because it is being used by another process.
```

I could combine the apps into one application, but I'd rather not.  Any suggestions would be appreciated as to how I can successfully log from both apps simultaneously.

Thank you.

Comment: Check that the names in your `LoggerToMatch` config are exactly equal to the names used when you create the logger in your code. You also need to uncomment the `<filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />` section to stop other loggers using the appender - see [this blog post](http://www.claassen.net/geek/blog/2009/06/log4net-filtering-by-logger.html) for good examples of how to use filters.

Comment: Stuart,  thank you.  I originally had the DenyAllFilter on for the reason you mention, but kept wondering if they were conflicting with each other.  I've also verified the LoggerToMatchValue by copying the namespace and class name.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html, under the section **How do I get multiple process to log to the same file?**

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+InterProcessLock" />
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, which is how to write to *different* log files.